# Fine tuning InceptionV3 in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am implementing a Convolutional Neural Net using transfer learning in Keras by using pre-trained InceptionV3 model from `keras.applications` like shown below

```
#Transfer learning with Inception V3
base_model = applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))

## set model architechture
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x) 
predictions = Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')(x) 
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

I was following a blog post that said the model must be trained for a few epochs after freezing the base model. I have trained the model for 5 epochs which gave me acc of 0.47. After that acc don't improve much. Then I stopped the training and unfreezed some of the layers like this and freezing first 2 Convolution layers.

```
for layer in model.layers[:172]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[172:]:
   layer.trainable = True
```

And compiled with SGD with lower learning rate.

Was my approach to stop training the model when the acc don't improve much with layers freezed correct.? Should I have trained longer.?

How to know the correct time to stop training with layers freezed.?

Comment: If you're using a fixed image size, you don't need the GlobalAveragePooling. This layer reduces a lot the amount of vars you have for the Dense layer. It may be a lot easier to find better acc values with a Flatten instead of that pooling. (The downside is that you will not be able to use images with different sizes later).

Comment: If you do plan to use variable size images later, then maybe `GlobalMaxPooling2D` could be a little better. Since convolutional networks work by detecting the presence of certain features, MaxPooling will fit the idea of "maximum value = most trustable indicator of presence". While average pooling will sum presence (high) and absence (low) values and result always in a "kind of present" result.

Comment: If you notice that the `Flatten` model works way better than any `GlobalPooling` models, you can try adding a `Conv2D(1024,activation='relu')` before the pooling. (This will create a feature map for each of the desired classes before maxpooling. But it's probably less useful if the last inception layer does not already have 1024 or more filters).

Comment: Ok. I will give it a go.

Comment: How long should I train with my base_model layers freezed.? Till acc remains to be constant.? Or should  I over fit it slightly.?

Comment: Training the model with Flatten gives huge loss of 15.6.

Comment: You should train for long enough to see that your accuracy is not getting any better. There isn's a defined number. Each problem is different. Keep training (it may take lots of time indeed). I don't think you should make the inception model trainable before you've got a very good accuracy. ---- It's normal to get bigger losses and slower training with the flatten (you will have way more variables for training, but it will eventually find a better result at the end)

Comment: Ok. I will try and let you know the results,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you don't have to train your randomly initialized layers until loss/accuracy stops improving.

When I used InceptionV3 for fine-tuning I trained my additional Dense layer for just 2 epochs, even though training it for few more epochs would most likely lead to better loss/accuracy.
The number of epochs for initial training depends on your problem and data.
(For me 2 epochs reached ~40%.)

I thinks it's a waste of time to train only Dense layer for too long.
Train it to get something considerably better that random initialization.
Then unfreeze more layers and train them longer together with your Dense layer.
As soon as your Dense layer gives reasonable predictions, it's good to train other layers, especially that you have batch normalization in InceptionV3 that stabilizes the variance of gradients for earlier layers.